# Command in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have really simple code but it does not work.

I have a command :

```
public class SetYesCommand : ICommand , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        ViewModelBase view = new ViewModelBase();

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            view.Sname = "Yes";
            MessageBox.Show("Command works");
            onpropertychanged("Sname");
        }

        private void onpropertychanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is my base view model class :

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private  string _s;
        public  string Sname {
            get { return _s; }
            set { _s = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Sname");
            }

        }

        private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

and this is my XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
         xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.Commands"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:ViewModelBase  x:Key="base" ></viewmodel:ViewModelBase>
        <viewmodel:Converters  x:Key="convert" ></viewmodel:Converters>
        <commands:SetYesCommand x:Key="setyes"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Command="{StaticResource setyes}"/>
        <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource base}" Text="{Binding Sname , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox DataContext="{StaticResource base}" IsChecked="{Binding Sname , Mode=TwoWay , Converter={StaticResource convert}}"  />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see simply I bound two element in my UI to a string property in my view model base class and I defiend a command for my button in UI. The command works because as you see I check it with a messagebox but the value of two other element ( textbox and checkbox) in my UI do not change.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of ViewModelBase in your command. It's is the view model that should create the command and not the other way around.

Comment: @mm8 I tried it with static properties too and it does not work in that way too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `ViewModelBase` in your command. It's is the view model that should create the command and not the other way around.

An typical implementation of the `ICommand` interface generally accepts an `Action<object>` to be executed and a `Predicate<object>` that decides whether to execute the command:

```
public class SetYesCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public SetYesCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
            return true;
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

The logic is then implemented in the view model:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _s;
    public string Sname
    {
        get { return _s; }
        set
        {
            _s = value;
            onPropertyChanged("Sname");
        }

    }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        TheCommand = new SetYesCommand(OnCommandExecuted, null);
    }

    private void OnCommandExecuted(object parameter)
    {
        Sname = "Yes";
        MessageBox.Show("Command works");
    }

    public ICommand TheCommand { get; private set; }

    private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In the view, you bind to a command property of the view model that returns an instance of your `ICommand` implementation:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="30" DataContext="{StaticResource base}" Command="{Binding TheCommand}"/>
```

Comment: That is so good thank you but still I can not undestand why even when my property was static it did not work.

Comment: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties

Answer (score 2):

You seem rather confused regarding the relationship between command and viewmodel.

The command object should be a property of the viewmodel, not the other way around.

Start with a basic generic ICommand implementation

```
public class BasicCommand: ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public BasicCommand(Action execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Than in your viewmodel, define the command as a property something like this

```
public class MyViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand = new BasicCommamd(()=>OnDoSomething());
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand {get;}

    private void OnDoSomething()
    {
        // put whatever you want the command to do here
    }
}
```

You can now set the DataContext of your Window to be an instance of MyViewModel, and bind the button's command property to DoSomethingCommand.

Comment: Yea I am new to MVVM and I am some kind of confused, Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at my blog then for my take on WPF / MVVM - http://peregrinesview.uk/

Answer (score 2):

You are creating new instance of ViewModelBase inside SetYesCommand, so view.Sname = "Yes" does not change Sname property on view model bound to elements.

This is working:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel"
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModel.Commands"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:ViewModelBase  x:Key="base" ></viewmodel:ViewModelBase>
        <viewmodel:Converters  x:Key="convert" ></viewmodel:Converters>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource base},Path=YesCommand}"/>
        <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource base}" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource base},Path=Sname , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <CheckBox DataContext="{StaticResource base}" IsChecked="{Binding Sname , Mode=TwoWay , Converter={StaticResource convert}}"  />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _s;

        private Commands.SetYesCommand _yesCommand;

        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            _yesCommand = new SetYesCommand(this);
        }

        public string Sname
        {
            get { return _s; }
            set
            {
                _s = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Sname");
            }

        }

        public SetYesCommand YesCommand => _yesCommand;

        private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

public class SetYesCommand : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ViewModelBase view;

    public SetYesCommand(ViewModelBase view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        view.Sname = "Yes";
        MessageBox.Show("Command works");
        onpropertychanged("Sname");
    }

    private void onpropertychanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```