# ListBox in WPF app is not updating when removing from bound ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, observablecollection, listbox-control

I have googled so much on this topic that my hands are bleeding before writing this question. What I have gathered so far is that I know I have to use an `ObservableCollection`.

The `ListBox` populates on startup, but the problem occurs when I want to delete/remove an item from the `ObservableCollection` and have it reflected in the `ListBox`.

The item is removed from the `ObservableCollection` but the `ListBox` does not update anything. I have tried different bindings like Mode and `UpdateSourceTrigger`.

This is my code so far:

```
<ListBox Name="projectsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,5,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}" FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel. The ViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase which in turn inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class OpenProjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ProjectData> _projects;

    public ObservableCollection<ProjectData> Projects
    {
        get { return _projects; }
        set
        {
            if (_projects != value)
            {
                _projects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Projects));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code that removes the item from the `ObservebleCollection`:

```
Projects
    .Remove(Projects
    .Where(_ => _.Id == id).Single());
```

**Update**: one thing to note is in `OpenProjectView` I have a `OnDelete_Click` button, I have instantiated the `OpenProjectViewModel` which holds the delete logic for the `ObservableCollection`. The `ObservableCollection` is instantiated in the constructor. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

```
private void OnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenProjectViewModel openProjectViewModel = new();//<--The ObservableCollection is instantiated in the constructor
    openProjectViewModel.DeleteProject(listItem);
}
```

Did I forget to share anything?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Are you sure that you did not accidently re-set / re-assigned a value to your "Projects" property during runtime? I do not see it on the code you posted, but I made that error in the past myself, then I wondered why the UI was not updating correctly.

Comment: You could check the return value of `Projects.Remove` to verify that in fact an item has been removed.

Comment: @KlausGütter from the actual code:
 var successfullyDeleted = Projects
                .Remove(Projects
                .Where(_ => _.FullPath == projectData.FullPath && _.ProjectName == projectData.ProjectName).Single());

Comment: @Martin hmm. good point. checked, and I cant find any reassigns or resets, unfortunately.

Comment: Updated the question with new thoughts.

Comment: `openProjectViewModel = new();` does of course create a new instance of the view model, which is obviously not the one to which the UI is bound. You may write `var openProjectViewModel = (OpenProjectViewModel)DataContext;`

Comment: @Clemens That did it! The ListBox is updating! Is there a way to do this in the xaml view? Right now I only have 
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:OpenProjectViewModel/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>
in the view.

Comment: The "OpenProjectViewModel" should be created only one time, for example in the constructor of the view. Afterwards the view shall use only this instance. I would implement the delete logic using a button that is bound to an "DeleteCommand" which is of type "ICommand" and resides in the "OpenProjectsViewModel".  See also this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781651/4424024   If you want to delete the currently selected item in the list, you should bound the "SelectedItem" property if the ListBox to a new property "SelectedProject" property in the viewmodel.

Comment: @Clemens make your suggestion an answer and I will mark it as solved. :)

Comment: I am hesitating to say the following, because I would strictly advise against a UserControl setting its own DataContext. But instead of assigning the DataContext in XAML you could create it in the UserControl's code behind as a field: `private readonly OpenProjectViewModel openProjectViewModel = new OpenProjectViewModel();`. In the control's constructor set `DataContext = openProjectViewModel;` and wherever else you need it, just use the field.